# How to make parent element hide but child inside be visible

Tags: html, css

I have a simple backstretch slideshow and inside of this is navigation list.It's responsive web and I want the backstretch slideshow dissapear, but navlist to stay when the width is smaller than 540px.
Code:

```
<div class="backstretch">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id=""><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id=""><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id=""><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the parent visibility to `hidden` and child's to `visible`.

Try:

```
.backstretch>ul
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.backstretch
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xw7d203y/2/)